Create radial gradient that blends into the background in Photoshop
The following is an example image which I've cropped from a youtube thumbnail where the gradient is placed on the top left. What I'd like to do is create a complete circular gradient shape which fades outwards, blending into whatever background color the layer it's placed on has. How can I do this in Photoshop 2020 ?


Batman, you can have Alfred Google that for you.

If I've understood your question, you can just use the gradient tool for this.
Set up a gradient with a colour stop, and a black stop (you can also use the same colour as the first stop if you want). Then set outer stop opacity to 0%.
Draw your gradient on a new transparent layer
See the outer stop highlighted in red below, and the opacity adjusted.

Here it is on a different background

